# Recyclerview not clickable android studio (maybe my code error?)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

so i have a recycler view that has inside 2 labels and an image. i need when this recyclerView is clicked to navigate to second activity..I dont know what im doing wrong..i mean **my recyclerView its still not clickable**

Main activity code :

```
RecyclerView relative1 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.result_list);
        relative1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // viewResults class is the class that starts the second activity.
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewResults.class));
            }
        });
```

And this is the ViewResults.java

```
public class ViewResults extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //here i try to start the new activity when recycler view is clicked
        setContentView(R.layout.secondActivity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the whole RecyclerView clickable?

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous yes mate

Comment: @tryingmybest So you want the recyclerview as a whole to be clickable? Not the items within (which is the usual use case)? If so, you probably have to use `setClickable` and `setFocusable`

Comment: You can not make RecyclerView clickable, it overrides onTouchEvent and doesn't handle clicks. You can try to use GestureDetector to handle clicks or extend RecyclerView and return clicking logic back.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class use `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener`

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
           Toast.makeText(context, "Your logic comes here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    })
```

And removed this block of code because you need to set click listeners on individual views within the RecyclerView, rather than the RecyclerView as a whole.

```
recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to setOnClick from your activity class then make the interface in your adapter class. flow the blew adapter code.**

```
public class AdapterClass_Recycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass_Recycler.ViewClass> {
Context context;
private static ClickListener clickListener;

public AdapterClass_Recycler(MainActivity mainActivity) {

    this.context = mainActivity;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewClass onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);

    return new ViewClass(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewClass viewClass, int i) {


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return length;
}


public class ViewClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener {


    public ViewClass(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        return false;
    }

}


public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    AdapterClass_Recycler.clickListener = clickListener;
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);
}
```

}

**Then set onclick from your activity**

```
 adapterClassObject.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterClass_Recycler.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(int position, View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```